# check that $p(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ is a density function

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have to prove the following is a density function
$p(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ when $t>=0$.

$p(t) = 0$  for $t<0$

If I understand correctly, if solve the integral, I should get $1$, because this the definition of a density function.

I tried the following...

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$
...which resulted in...
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}[(-\lambda e^{-\lambda t})/\lambda]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$$

I do not know how to proceed. If I just plug in the infinities then I $0$ I think. How do I check if the function is a density function?

Comment: Please be more precise with notation. An integral is performed w.r.t a variable; so for example, $\int f(x)$ has no meaning in and of itself

Comment: Why did you do a *double* integral, and over what variable did you integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, checking that the integral is 1 is the correct approach.

Secondly, why the double integral when there is only one dependent variable $t$? My tip is: be careful with notation and use the proper definitions! Define a density function as

$$ \int_A p(t) \mathrm{d}t = 1 $$

where p(t) is defined for the entire set $A$. So what you should try instead to do is

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} p(t) \mathrm{d}t = \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \mathrm{d}t = \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \left [ \frac{1}{-\lambda}\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \right ]_{0}^{\epsilon} = \\
=  \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \left ( - e^{-\lambda \epsilon} - (-e^{-\lambda 0}) \right ) = \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \left ( 1 - e^{-\lambda \epsilon} \right ) $$

where at the first equals sign i used $p(t) = 0 \forall t < 0$. We then simply solve the limit as

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \left ( 1 - e^{-\lambda \epsilon} \right ) = 1 $$

as $\lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} e^{-\lambda \epsilon} \mapsto 0$ IF $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong, but sending $\epsilon\to\infty$ in the limit made me cringe a little...

Comment: Haha considering the notation in the question i allowed myself some slight notation barbarism x)

Actually... do they even teach the epsilon-delta proofs anymore except for a math-masters?

Comment: @5xum Why is $$ \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} p(t) \mathrm{d}t = \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \mathrm{d}t$$?

And I thought the notation $ \lim_{\epsilon \mapsto \infty} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} p(t) \mathrm{d}t$ is wrong

Comment: @ZeroPancakes It's because $p(t)=0$ for $t<0$. This means $$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon p(t)dt = \int_{-\epsilon}^0 p(t)dt + \int_0^\epsilon p(t)dt = \int_{-\epsilon}^0 0 dt + \int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt.$$

I don't know why you think the notation $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon p(t)dt$ is wrong, can you explain?

Comment: @5xum Oh I see now. Well, I'm taking integral calculus classes right now, studying from Spivak's calculus. We had to cover improper integrals, which I think are not covered in the book and the professor told us that notation is wrong. I asked why and she said that sometimes it does works, but it is not the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$

Comment: @5xum Spivak's calculus, ch. 14, ex. 27: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=\int_{0}^{\infty}f+\int_{-\infty}^{0}f$ by definition. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdx$ exists, but $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^{N}xdx$ doesn't

Comment: @ZeroPancakes You're right, but since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(t) dt $ exists, the equation $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon dt= \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(t)dt$ is correct.

Comment: @5xum Ok, so if I understood correctly, when we don't know from the beginning that a limit $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$ exists, we should first use the definition $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=\int_{-\infty}^{0}f+\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ to calculate it, and if it really exists then it is okay to use the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=\lim_{N \to \infty} {\int_{-N}^{N}f}$. Correct?

Comment: If you guys are interested in the intricacies of limits i suggest reading into the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition (in my opinion the only proper one) of the limit:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Then try proving some simple facts with it. And then apply it to a improper integral and see what happens :)

Comment: Also, instead of just "using the fact that $p(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$" we can also use a distribution function (they are defined by integrals, not describable by regular functions):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

and build this into the function directly by defining 

$$ p(t) = \theta(t) \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \;\forall\; t \in \mathbb{R}$$

where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function